# Display HTML file using UIWebView that has subdirectories and external js/img files

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In Objective C, I want to display a website that I have built using UIWebView.

Brief Overview: I have a folder that has index.html. Inside that folder, there is an "img" folder and a "js" folder. The js folder has many .js files. The img folder has many images. I can run the page independently (outside of xcode) no problem.

Now I was able to create a very basic html file, store it in the same directory as all of my .h and .m files, and get it to display correctly. My goal now is to display my website with subdirectories as I just explained above.

Here is what I've got so far:

**xCode:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] path:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSLog(path);
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:baseURL];
}
```

**Here is what my file structure looks like:**

[image]

When I run it, the build succeeds. But nothing is displayed. In addition, I can check the
"Issue Navigator" tab (on the left Navigator) to see a list of issues. What I notice is that for every .js file that I included in my game.html file, there is an issue. They all state basically the same thing:

> Dependency Analysis Warning: warning: no rule to process file
>   '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Web/gameFolder/js/input/MouseInputHandler.js' of type
>   sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386

So what can I do?

Thanks: Captainlonate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*Dependency Analysis Warning: warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Web/gameFolder/js/input/MouseInputHandler.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386*
```

After you've added your html-related files to the project, *.js files were added to the "compile sources" list in "build phases". So the compiler tried to compile them, but he cannot, therefore the warning (plus they don't really get copied to the bundle). This default behavior once cost me good few minutes of exasperation...

Remove them (*.js files) from this list and add to "copy bundle resources"

Another thing is - in the bundle, all your resources' hierarchy gets "flattened". I mean, if you had your files like that:

```
index.html
js/lib/jquery.js
img/circle.png
```

you've had probably done something like

```
<img src="img/circle.png">
```

but it won't work in webview. You'll have to referr to the very same file like that:

```
<img src="circle.png">
```

because the webview sees your files in the bundle in that way:

```
index.html
jquery.js
circle.png
```

Yet another thing - you load your web content by loading the HTML file as a string and then you pass it to the webview. It's not really bad, but I believe that it's a bit better to use other approach:

```
NSBundle* mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* path = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"index" ofType: @"html"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
[webview loadRequest: req];
```

Comment: And Just like that, my html5 game runs! LOL